# How can I allow my regular user to chown files, via setfacl?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I am using ACL to set specific permissions in a directory:

`setfacl -R -m u:wordpress:wrx /var/www/html/wp`

As that user, I am able to create a subdirectory within the directory with `mkdir test`, but if I then want to change the ownership with `chown apache:apache test`, I get an `operation not permitted` error.

Is there any way to give the wordpress user the ability to change ownership of files within the wp directory which has been set with setfacl?

Answer (score 0):

Preventing ownership changes is not a filesystem/Access Control Lists feature, it's a UNIX feature designed to [prevent bad things from happening](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27374/24471).

I suppose you *could* give the `wordpress` user the permission to `chown` via `sudoers` if you really wanted to, but I would question the reasons for trying to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A regular user can not change a file's owner, but she can change it's group ownership if the user is in that group. So first add `wordpress` to the `apache` group. Then `wordpress` should be able to use `chgrp` on the file. You'll probably have to use `newgrp apache` first. So the process is:

```
# As root
$ sudo usermod --groups apache wordpress

# As wordpress
$ newgrp apache
$ chgrp apache test
$ ls -ld test
drwxrwxr-x 2 wordpress apache 4096 Jul  2 13:15 test/
```

But as mentioned before, this is probably not a wise thing to do. You would be better off configuring apache and wordpress to work well together.